# How do I load a View with a View name? For example, I have a struct TextPage: View , how do I load this View via the string TextPage?

Tags: swiftui

How do I load a View with a View name? For example, I have a `struct TextPage: View` , how do I load this View via the string TextPage ?

Comment: are you trying to load the `TextPage` view as the root view of the app or are you trying to push it onto a navigation stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [UIHostingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller)

```
UIHostingController(rootView: TextPage())
```